# Open a folder and save all the files in another folder

Tags: php, scandir

How can I open the directory selection box on the server, choose a folder and when I click `submit` all the files in the old folder go to the new folder?

```
<form method="post" action="folder.php">
   <input type="file" name="folder" id="folder"></td> </tr>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

$OldFolder = $_POST['folder'];

$newFolder = "/newFolder";
```

Comment: `<input type="file">` doesn't open folders on the server, but on your local machine

Comment: @SalvatoreQZeroastro yes I do not know how to do just to get the directory

Comment: You can't use a standard file selection dialog to select files on the server. Write a PHP loop that gets all the folder names and creates a form with them listed in a `<select>`.